# QFileDialog::getOpenFileName открывается снизу окна приложения

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt5

Проблема описана в заголовке, система Ubuntu 22.04, в приложении есть диалог добавления файла, при открытии диалога и нажатии кнопки "обзор" открывается окно QFileDialog::getOpenFileName, но почему то снизу всех окон и даже при фокусе не выходит поверх, не понимаю почему, на Windows Открывается поверх всегда.

Comment: приведите минимально воспроизводимый пример. в ubuntu 20.04 все нормально

Comment: спасибо, уже не актуально, поставил винду на комп